# Roadmap to build simple android application without installing android sdk/ndk provided by google

Tags: android

I want to build an android application for my personal needs, and have almost no programming knowledge, so I hope my question makes sense (I am willing to learn if there is a specific guideline/roadmap). The application I need is supposed to use [remind](https://dianne.skoll.ca/projects/remind/) as a calendar backend, push the notifications to the device. The android sdk/ndk are huge, and have license issues as well (non-free).

Based on my search, I understand that you would only need some development kit to build the apk file, but I could not find any unofficial alternative to sdk and ndk provided by google (CrystalX uses the same license agreement, and is old, so it is out of question).

I have been thinking whether it is possible to either build a web application or integrate remind in another application (like termux) with proper sync and notification support or not. If your solution does not fit either if these two I would still like to know more.

P.S. I know about remind-caldav, but it doesn't suit my use case.

Comment: The SDK and NDK are free.  They're also not part of your app-  you link to them.  They're part of the OS.  So you won't be making copies of them anyway, meaning copyright isn't an issue.  And any app on ANdroid will be using one of those, either directly or indirectly.  Because it's literally the OS interface.

Comment: Also we have no idea what you mean by "remind". If it's an Android or Linux app, it's not as common as you think it is.  So at least a link would be necessary.  But to push notifications to a device you need an app on the device which listens for incoming push messages.  Which requires a mobile app, which requires the SDK.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks. I added the link to the application I mentioned. I understand that license agreement wouldn't exactly restrict my work, but I whink it is unfair. However, my main problem is with its size. I am both low on storage and internet. I know there are online app builders (I haven't used any), so in case there is no other option to integrate the remind, they seem plausible as well.

Comment: You need an app on the actual device to get push notices to set up notifications.  That's completely unavoidable-  something on the device has to display a notification. You can't just send a notification to a phone and it will display it, (you can't send a Notification at all, that's a mobile concept.  You can send a data message that an app on the phone shows a notification in response to.  There is no such thing as sending a generic notification).

Comment: And if you dislike the license for the SDK, I suggest you look at hose mobile app builders.  They'll be FAR worse.  They also will use more internet, and likely more storage, than a native app.

Comment: @GabeSechan I see, thanks. Just a few questions. What is a hose app builder? About generic notifications, is it possible to build an app similar to termux which loads chuncks of code, like pocketpy or lua, to increase modularity?

Comment: It was a typos, I meant to say those.  Sorry.  That's what happens when I type on mobile.